# @Autowired annotation is not working in spring standalone application

Tags: spring

I'm new to spring , and I'm trying to use @Autowired annotation in my standalone app, but I couldn't make it.
Here is my main class

**MainDemo.java**

```
public class MainDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BeanFactory sf= new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("beans.xml")); 

    SpringIntro a= (SpringIntro)sf.getBean("act");
    System.out.println(a.getResults());
}
```

**SpringIntro.java**

```
@Service("act") 
public class SpringIntro {

@Autowired
AdminInterface adminDAO;

public String getResults(){
    System.out.println("in spring intro");
    for( AdminBean ab:adminDAO.getAdminData() ){
        System.out.println(ab.getAdministratiorName());
    }
    return "sree";
}
}
```

**Admininterface.java**

```
  public interface AdminInterface {
    List<AdminBean> getAdminData();
    }
```

**AdminDao.java**

```
public class AdminDao implements AdminInterface{
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Override
    public List<AdminBean> getAdminData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("admin dao autowired is working "+jdbcTemplate);
        String sql = "select * from administrator";
        List<AdminBean> resultList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
                new AdminMapping());
        return resultList;
    }

}
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbschool" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="spinsci" />
    </bean>
<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">

      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    

    </bean>
```

when I run app through main method i'm getting null pointer, If add beans for adminDao in beans.xml file i'm getting the result, but If I use @Autowired I'm having problems. Can any one help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You using XmlBeanFactory, but XmlBeanFactory doesn't implements BeanPostProcessor and does not postprocess annotations: then it doesn't use AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. That might cause your null pointer exception.

I suggest you use ApplicationContext instead.

Comment: Or just Spring Boot, which would eliminate the need for half of this.